# Several data type with Type constructor accepting the same Type, how to get same name accessor ?

Tags: haskell

Short : I have a solution to my problem, but it seems overkill so I wonder if I miss something.

Long :
I have a 2 data Type, an Animal type and an Owner type. Both have same "attributes" age and name. For sake of simplicity, I want to be able to call age and name indifferenly on Animal and on Owner

```
type Age = Int
type Name = String

data AnimalType = Dog | Cat | Snake
 deriving (Read, Show,Eq)

--with  datatype and pattern matching
data Animal = Animal AnimalType Name Age
 deriving(Show, Eq)
name (Animal _ name _) = name 
age (Animal _ _ age) = age 
animalType (Animal animalType _ _) = animalType 

data Owner = Owner Name Age [Animal]
 deriving(Show,Eq)
name    (Owner name _      _) = name 
age     (Owner _    age    _) = age
animals (Owner _    _      animals) = animals

garfield = Animal Cat "Garfield" 8
rantanplan = Animal Dog "Rantanplan " 4
kaa = Animal Snake "Kaa" 15

dupond = Owner "Dupont" 28 [garfield, rantanplan]
bob = Owner "Bob" 35 [kaa]
```

This does not compile,

```
  Multiple declarations of `age'
```

The same thing does not work neither with Record syntax.

Doing so, one is forced to name differently age for Owner and age for Animal.

Then I dug a bit and found out that I could use typeclass to achieve that.

```
type Age = Int
type Name = String

class Nameable a where
 name:: a -> Name

class Ageable a where
 age:: a -> Age


data AnimalType = Dog | Cat | Snake
 deriving (Read, Show,Eq)

--with  datatype and pattern matching
data Animal = Animal AnimalType Name Age
 deriving(Show, Eq)

instance Nameable Animal where
 name (Animal _ name _) = name 

instance Ageable Animal where
 age (Animal _ _ age) = age

animalType (Animal animalType _ _) = animalType 


data Owner = Owner Name Age [Animal]
 deriving(Show,Eq)

instance Nameable Owner where 
 name (Owner name _ _) = name

instance Ageable Owner where
 age (Owner _ age _) = age

animals (Owner _    _      animals) = animals



garfield = Animal Cat "Garfield" 8
rantanplan = Animal Dog "Rantanplan " 4
kaa = Animal Snake "Kaa" 15

dupond = Owner "Dupont" 28 [garfield, rantanplan]
bob = Owner "Bob" 35 [kaa]
```

This approach is almost identical to usage of Interface in Java. The first one that does not work is closer to old C struct approach.

is there a quicker way to achieve the same result ?

Comment: Turn on `DuplicateRecordFields` and the records approach will work

Comment: A very similar question here [Haskell record accessors shared by different constructors of the same data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907974/haskell-record-accessors-shared-by-different-constructors-of-the-same-data-type). Provided your duplicate record accessors point to the same type i guess it should work.

Comment: @Redu no, here we have 2 different data types, `Animal` and `Owner`.

Comment: @Will Ness Yes you are right my bad.

Comment: @GhostCat : maybe you right for this case. Otherwise,  no offence,but you should wonder what is worst : making a wrong triage or polluting a post with a private message not related at all to the topic. Best Regards

Answer (score 6):

Records (and their accessors) in Haskell are... suboptimal. That said, this particular issue regarding duplicate record fields has a workaround (since GHC 8.0) in the form of the [`DuplicateRecordFields`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#duplicate-record-fields) extension. Note that the record accessors have to be used in an unambiguous fashion (there is no fancy polymorphism happening here).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}

type Age = Int
type Name = String

data AnimalType = Dog | Cat | Snake
  deriving (Read, Show, Eq)

data Animal = Animal
  { animalType :: AnimalType
  , name :: Name
  , age :: Age
  } deriving(Show, Eq)

data Owner = Owner
  { name :: Name
  , age :: Age
  , animals :: [Animal]
  } deriving(Show, Eq)

garfield = Animal Cat "Garfield" 8
rantanplan = Animal Dog "Rantanplan " 4
kaa = Animal Snake "Kaa" 15

dupond = Owner "Dupont" 28 [garfield, rantanplan]
bob = Owner "Bob" 35 [kaa]
```

Comment: `main = print $ name bob` gives compiler error on ideone (8.0.1) and [tio](https://tio.run/##fVFNT8JAEL33V7wsHjApBz9ICAmHKkiMBpOip4bD0C5L0@22tovEIH/dutsC1Ri97O7MvJn35u2ayoRLWe16HTx6s@mLN51gvMllHJLmPg@zIrqLuYxKdHp7B45@zzk8wTHCvdJNOKPUxnNdxEoYTESa4Kk4Jfls6yOMM4EP3JI251xRwh0g4kX8ZhrQ9TlFLubrbOti8nr@c4Lpbh6mZQdqpw6H3zhM0YWyOkza6qkTJBqYsOH@xNj9RfW0VbwwTPVdE/0/yz0IKW0qaGQs/uYQVKysiaddaivY9JBmGDgFKU0ql6RakHWN@W2B4dpJiFpAbSXYAxHDRd8us8kzFR0XARvbWDNcDhAcRbhouRbOMlu28JtsyXDVR2BYFqjMwJRiKyg3P6tx1rhiWqrqM1xJEmX1BQ) (8.0.2) both; works OK with OP's last code, which uses type classes.

Comment: Tip: `DuplicateRecordFields` works well with `NamedFieldPuns` and `RecordWildcards`, both for creating records and extracting fields. So one can write for example `let Animal {name} = Animal Cat "Garfield" 8` without interfering with similar code for `Owner` in another function.

Comment: (had to disambiguate it by writing `main = print $ (name :: Owner -> Name) bob`).

Comment: I haven't used `DuplicateRecordFields` - is there any downside except for disambiguating, how are they working with `lenses`?

Comment: @Alec,  with the  DuplicateRecordFields  extension, the file loads correctly  in GHCi , but then no way to invoke name, even with the disambiguate trick, I still have the ambigous error. (using GHCi version 8.2.1). Any idea why ?

Comment: @sandwood [here's one](https://tio.run/##fVFNT8JAFLzvr5gsHiBpD36QEBJMqiAxGkyonpoeHnQtDe22LovEIL@97raUaoxe2r735s3Mm65osxZpWu7dDh692fTFm04w3hZpsiQt5mKZq@guEWm0Qcc9MDD9UQh4scAI91LX5YwyW/taJTI2mIg0wZNJRumznY8wzmN84pa0efqS1oIBkVDJu1lAdy4ocuCv8p2DyVvvJ4PZrj/Myh7Usg6H3zTM0IG0Pkzb@qkaFNew2JaHk2L3l9TTTgpllKp3JfQ/l3M0srGtoLYR/q0Rk3q1IZ5uqaLg02ObY8AUSU2ySEm2IJsan7cDjiu2JmoBVZTgD0Qc5317zLbIZdQcAj62tea4GCBoTDhotUK2yBct/CZfcFz2ERiVEKUhzCixhgrzZzXO0G1iqRfc6yqfHgxLWX4B) that works. Could you show your code that doesn't?

Comment: @sandwood You may need to explicitly add a type to the record accessor. I know, this is disappointingly verbose. The good news is that `DuplicateRecordFields` is only a stepping stone to a solution which should have fancy polymorphism (which would mean that your accessor would be well-typed and not tied to a particular field). Look up `OverloadedRecordFields` for more.